# Indexing an Enum type field with hibernate-search

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I am having problems searching using Hibernate search when the index I want to use is of an Enum type.

Here is an example of what my application looks like:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class MyEntity{
   @Id
   @Field 
   public Long id;
   @Field(bridge=@FieldBridge(impl=EnumBridge.class))
   public Flavour flavour;
}
```

with

```
public enum Flavour {
  vanilla,
  chocolate,
  strawberry,
  pistacchio;
}
```

Then I try to find all instances using this type of query.

```
QueryBuilder qb = [~] ;
Query q = qb.keyword().onField("flavour").matching(Flavour.vanilla).createQuery();
```

When I test this the results always comes empty. I even tried to see the content of the indexes using Luke and I do not seem to find "flavour". I do re-index everything after committing changes.
Everyother type of indexing works and querying works perfectly on anything but enum fields.

I have tried almost any combination of the `norms`, `analyze`, `index`, `store`, ... of the `@Field` annotation (I am using Hibernate-search 4.5.x with hibernate 4.3.1).

What am I doing wrong? Any settings I should be looking at? Any help is welcome.

Comment: Do you have a data sample?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The entity seems to store the flavour using the ordinal (so the column flavour contains 0 instead of "vanilla").

I don't know, what the EnumBridge is doing, but I would suggest to store the enumeration as a string:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class MyEntity{
    @Id
    @Field 
    public Long id;

    @Field(bridge=@FieldBridge(impl=EnumBridge.class))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public Flavour flavour;
}
```

Comment: This answer helped solve part of the problem (the biggest). But the main point is that without that annotation the DB use the ordinals (Which is bad because this format can be broken by reordering the enum constants like some auto-refactoring tools do).